# Как в предложении дать понять, что «включенное» относится к юридическому лицу?

Tags: грамотная-речь, запятые, союзы

Привлечь для охраны юридическое лицо и (или) физическое лицо, включенное в реестр.

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Фраза двусмысленная, понимай как хочешь. Вот "юридическое или физическое лицо" выглядит гораздо лучше.

Comment: с п а с и б о !

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно поменять местами слова: "Привлечь для охраны включенные в реестр юридическое лицо и (или) физическое лицо".

Comment: спасибо! изменить уже нельзя

Answer (score 0):

Я точно не знаю, с точки зрения грамматики, но на мой взгляд, если «включенное в реестр» относится только к юридическому лицу лучше взять это в скобки.

*Привлечь для охраны физическое лицо и/или юридическое лицо (включенное в реестр).*